# What are the chances for blockage of messages in persistent queues in mule?

Tags: asynchronous, mule, message-queue, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I read that message loss in persistent queues is zero,but I want to know the chances for blockage of  messages in persistent queues in Mulesoft. If it happens what are the ways to rectify that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Persistent queues ensures zero message loss, sometimes messages can get stuck and needs to be cleared, you need to check queues in Mule Management Console, if you have Enterprise Edition you can manage queues there.

Similar feature of queues is available in CloudHub as well. Also checkout, official documentation of MuleSoft.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.4/configuring-queues#configuring-queues